# How do I fix an indirect weight paint change error?

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting

[image: The Problem]

I've been having this error for the last few days now in different variations: Sometimes I move/rotate a bone and in an unrelated mesh an objects moves around it like shown in the picture.

This is based on a custom armature system I've created since the model(imported .obj file) has four legs and not much of a head.

Is there anyway to make the items stay in place when rotating it?

Comment: looks to me like your vertex weights are messed up.

Comment: And how would I go about fixing that? I'm still relatively new at Blender.